# underscore.js reduce error? different behavior than Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, underscore.js

It appears that the reduce method of underscore.js assumes that the 'memo' value is a scalar, whereas Ruby will accept a general object. Would this be a bug, a limitation of underscore.js or am I somehow screwing up?

Here is a trivial example of reduce in Ruby 1.9.3.

```
irb(main):020:0> a = [1, 1, 2, 2]
=> [1, 1, 2, 2]
irb(main):021:0> a.reduce([]) {|accum, nxt| accum.push(nxt)}
=> [1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Here is what I believe to be the equivalent code using _.js

```
var _ =Underscore.load();
function tryReduce() {
 var a = [1, 1, 2, 2]
 var b = _.reduce(a, function(out, nxt) {
   return out.push(nxt);
 }, [])
 Logger.log(b)
}
```

In Google Script the code bombs with

```
TypeError: Cannot find function push in object 1. (line 6, file "tryingStuff")
```

However this code runs and gives the correct result, 1006.

```
var _ =Underscore.load();
function tryReduce() {
 var a = [1, 1, 2, 2]
 var b = _.reduce(a, function(out, nxt) {
   return out + nxt;
 }, 1000)
 Logger.log(b)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `Array#push` returns different values in each language. While [Ruby's](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-push) returns the `Array` itself, [JavaScript's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the updated `length`.

`_.reduce()` can work with `Array` memos, but you have to ensure that the `Array` is what's returned in the iterator:

```
var b = _.reduce(a, function(out, nxt) {
   out.push(nxt);
   return out;
}, [])
```

Otherwise, the 1st round ends with a `Number` (the `length`) and the next round throws an error since `Number#push` doesn't exist. This is the "*scalar*" you mentioned:

> It appears that the reduce method of underscore.js assumes that the 'memo' value is a scalar